# Regex para substituir vírgula e espaços juntos

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho o texto na string abaixo:

```
string = "ele, joao     gosta  de   maria,   mas   maria gosta        de jose";

string = string.replace(/???/g,", ");
```

Veja que algumas palavras possuem mais ou menos espaços entre elas, e ainda podem possuir vírgulas após uma palavra, mas nunca um espaço antes de uma vírgula.

Como construir uma Regex no `replace` para se chegar ao resultado abaixo?

```
ele, joao, gosta, de, maria, mas, maria, gosta, de, jose
```

Ou seja, cada palavra separada por uma *vírgula e um espaço*.

Tentei algo assim: `string = string.replace(/,\s+/g,", ");` mas não deu muito certo. Ficam sobrando vírgulas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa regex funciona bem:

```
(,?\s+)
```

Entrada:

```
"ele, joao     gosta  de   maria,   mas   maria gosta        de jose"
```

Saida:

```
"ele, joao, gosta, de, maria, mas, maria, gosta, de, jose"
```

```js
let string = "ele, joao     gosta  de   maria,   mas   maria gosta        de jose"

string = string.replace(/,?\s+/g, ", ")

console.log(string)
```

#### Explicação

`,?` pega por uma virgula que pode ou não estar ali (opcional).

`\s+` pega por um ou mais espaços.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do [@Francisco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/62269/francisco) achei melhor, mas consegui também com esta regex abaixo, que vou deixar aqui como referência:

```
[,|\s]+
```

A regex casa qualquer ocorrência de *vírgula* e/ou sequência de *espaços*.

**Teste:**

```js
string = "ele, joao     gosta  de   maria,   mas   maria gosta        de jose";

string = string.replace(/[,|\s]+/g,", ");

console.log(string);
```

Comment: O problema é que essa regex também substitui o caractere `|`, ou seja: `'a|b'.replace(/[,|\s]+/g,", ")` resulta em `a, b`. Para evitar isso, remova o `|`, ou seja: `/[,\s]+/g`. Outra diferença para a outra resposta é que a sua também substitui várias vírgulas, ex: `'a,,,,b'` se torna `a, b`, e tb não exige espaços depois da vírgula (`a,b` se torna `a, b`, já a regex da outra resposta não modifica porque espera pelo menos um espaço depois da vírgula) - não que esteja totalmente errado, é só para apontar as diferenças mesmo :-)